# iPhone/Objective-C - Justified Alignment in UITextView or UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, string, uiwebview, alignment, uitextview

I have a very long string and i want to display it in a seperate view, but i do not know how to have justified alignment. I know the only alignments in UITextView are left, right and center, so i tried using a UIWebView with justified alignment using the code below

```
[description loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align='justify'>%@<div>",MY_TEXT] baseURL:nil];
```

but no success... The string has no linebreaks but it is displayed like the pictures below...

[image: UITextViewResult]

[image: UIWebViewResult]

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? the justification in the webview (second image) is working correctly. Linebreaks occur because the text is wrapping.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly... Does every line has the same size??? Why does the line break in "(221)-" first line??? The second line is two or three times bigger than the first...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another option that can be used: `CATextLayer`.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

It supports justified alignment.

Or you can use `CoreText` framework directly.

Also try this link [HERE](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/).

Comment: What should i post? I write 
    CATextLayer *Textlayer;
for a start, but when i build the message "CATextLayer undeclared" appears. I have imported <CoreText/CoreText.h> in my view-class but.......

Comment: Edit your question then put your code that your having problem with